# How to get number of columns which are blank or null values or 0 from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, select

I want to get the number of column from MySQL table which has no values, means which are blank or zero.
Actually, I want to measure the employee profile that how many fields he has filled and how many are left?
I am using MySQL with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way of doing this other than to manually sum every column.  Here is a somewhat concise way of doing this:

```
SELECT
    empId,
    IF(COALESCE(col1, '') = '', 1, 0) +
    IF(COALESCE(col2, '') = '', 1, 0) +
    ...
    IF(COALESCE(colN, '') = '', 1, 0) AS num_cols_missing
FROM yourTable;
```

We can replace `NULL` columns values with empty string, and then compare that result to empty string.  This means we can check for both `NULL` and empty with a single logical expression.

Comment: Thank you! You've helped me out big time with this.

Answer (score 0):

Given a table with this schema `Employee(id, fname, lname, dob)`

If you wanted to find the number of `Employee` rows which had `NULL` or empty `fname` then you would do the following...

```
SELECT COUNT(fname) AS 'number of empty fnames'
FROM `Employee`
WHERE `fname` IS NULL
     OR `fname` = '';
```

Of course you can expand that to find any `NULL` or empty field/column.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(max) = (
        SELECT stuff((
                    SELECT 'and ' + c.NAME + ' is null '
                    FROM sys.columns c
                    WHERE object_name(object_id) = 'yourtablename'
                    ORDER BY c.NAME
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 3, '')
        )

SET @Str = 'select * from ' + yourtablename + ' where ' + @Str

PRINT @Str

EXEC (@Str)
```